# c# send html email via outlook 2013

Tags: c#, html, outlook

I sent an html via outlook.

In the html, I aligned a word to the right, but in the received e-mail, the word is mixed - the first letter has become the last letter.

This only occurs when the first letter is a number.

I sent the following html:

```
<div dir="rtl" style="margin: 20px auto; width: 650px; text-align: center; font-family: Tahoma;">
  <table dir="rtl" style="width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: right; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 0; font-weight: normal; color: #000;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #d0f2f6; padding: 15px 20px; margin: 0; color: #135861; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400;">
          שלום&nbsp;
          <br /><br />
          המספר הוא:<br />
          <b dir="rtl" style="font-family:consolas">1fD9xG8j</b>
          <br /><br />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

But I got the following mail:

[image: you can see the received mail here]

Why does outlook change the word '1fD9xG8j' to 'fD9xG8j1' ?

This is the code in c# which sent the mail:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient(SmtpServer);
var message = new MailMessage();

message.Subject = subject.Trim();
message.Body = body.Trim();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614474/when-line-of-text-starts-with-a-number-a-number-shows-up-on-right-in-rtl-mode

Answer (score 2):

Remove dir="rtl" from Table tag and try.

Comment: Even without dir="rtl", it still sent messy.

Answer (score 2):

I saw, that many times, Outlook text editor adds code to the source code. This happens because Outlook is generating the email source code using mostly VML (Vector Markup Language) which causes changes in the code. There are add-ins to import a clean HTML source code, to an Outlook email, in order to get it displayed correctly.

I tried to get around the problem with the following code:

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="font-family:consolas;font-weight:bold;text-align:right">1fD9xG8j</div>
```

I changed dir="ltr", and added style text-align:right,
and it works!